# What is the use of "static" positioning in CSS?

Tags: css-position

I have checked many books and sites, where I can see that everyone is saying that it is a default property and we can not use top, right, bottom and left property, I can understand that. But if it is already predefined then why do we use it's syntax? Can anyone please tell me its use.
{position: static;}

Answer (score 0):

We use it's syntax simply because we can make an element on a webpage change positions multiple times. Whether it's for animation purposes or for a real application it's always nice to be able to bring it back to it's default behavior (for whatever reason necessary).

For example, if you wanted a responsive website with an image in a special area, you could set that image `position: relative` for wide screens. Then when the screen size is reduced you can set it back to `position: static` , which (in my opinion) is easier to handle when the screen size is small (mobile phones).